# GitVersion (Azure DevOps) " Gitversion could not determine which branch to treat as the development branch"

Tags: git, azure-devops, devops, gitversion

Running GitVersion via AzureDevops and receive the following error message when attempting to use on any branch except master (incl, pull request branches, etc.);

So far i've tried to resolve the issue via:

- Increasing the checkout depth
- Manually specifying the next version via the next-version setting

**Error:**

```
 Gitversion could not determine which branch to treat as the development branch
```

**Git Version File**

```
mode: Mainline
branches: 
  master:
    regex: master
    increment: Patch
assembly-informational-format: '{MajorMinorPatch}+Branch.{BranchName}{PreReleaseTag}'
major-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(breaking|major)'
minor-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(feature|minor)'
patch-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(fix|patch)'
commit-message-incrementing: Enabled
tag-prefix: '[vV]'
ignore:
  sha: []
```

**YAML Pipeline**

```
- task: gitversion/setup@0
  displayName: gitversion/setup
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '5.10.3'

- task: gitversion/execute@0
  displayName: gitversion/execute
  inputs:
    useConfigFile: true
    configFilePath: GitVersion.yml
```

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem in one of my repos. Out of the blue. I could not find any specific reason why it happened, but by investigating how GitVersion works, I came to the conclusion that the shallow fetch was the culprit.
I solved it by telling the pipeline to always fetch everything. I put this in my pipeline template, so hopefully this will not happen anymore.

```
- steps:
  - checkout: self
    fetchDepth: 0
```

Comment: Out of the blue this star happening to me as well. This resolve this. Beat this chat-gpt :)

Comment: chatgpt is not developed to think logically. It is just a 'plausible-sentences-generator'.

Comment: ChatGPT will suggest this answer once they update their database past Sep/2021... 

Answer (score 14):

I found the solution. The pipeline settings UI has a Shallow fetch setting.

1. Edit your pipeline, choose ..., and select Triggers.
2. Select YAML, Get sources, and untick Shallow fetch option, or set the desired depth

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It worked for me. After creating anew project on DevOps, this option is enabled by default.

Comment: Save my day, it worked for me.

Comment: Works or me too.

Answer (score 1):

You mention "Increasing the checkout depth", which hints at using a "sparse checkout" or "shallow repository" option your CI job (is this correct ?)

The drawback of a shallow repository is : the repo your CI job is running on doesn't have the history of your repo.

If your job needs to find out how many commits the current branch is ahead of `master`, it needs at least the part of history that links `master` to your current branch.

The easiest way is to turn off the sparse/shallow option,
another way can be to explicitly "deepen" the history for your branch :

```
git fetch --deepen=100 origin master
git fetch --deepen=100 origin [active branch]
```

Comment: You're using the wrong term here, it's a *shallow repository* not a *sparse checkout*. (Grabbing the wrong phrase out of my head seems to happen to me more often as I get older. I like to think of it as happening because I know more things, not because I'm getting old )

Comment: @torek : edited the answer to reflect that precision :)